# Weighted average of two frequencies

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, average

This should be really simple but I'm getting stuck and I'm probably extremely dumb..

I know that a machine receives two kind of parts:

Type 1 -> with frequency 50 per week, each one is processed for 20 minutes
Type 2 -> with frequency 100 per week, each one is processed for 8 minutes

It was told me to consider (in working hours) 1 week = 2400 minutes.

I have to calculate the average arrival rate of the machine and the average service time of the machine.

Average arrival rate of the machine = 50 pieces per week + 100 pieces per week = 150 pieces per week, this is simple since each piece counts as an arrival (they're all equal)

I'm confused with the Average service time per piece of the machine...

I tried:

the machine can serve 2400/20 type 1 pieces per week = 120
and 2400 / 8 type 2 pieces per week = 300

so average_service_rate = (120*50 + 300*100) / 150 = 240, but this is wrong according to my solution (which is 200)...

if I use service times it works:
time per each type 1 piece: 20 min
time per each type 2 piece: 8 min
average_time_per_piece = (20*50 + 8*100)/150 = 12 min, i.e. 12/2400 week
so 1/averaget_time_per_piece = average_service_rate = 2400/12 = 200. And this is the right value.

My question is: why my first approach with the average frequency didn't work? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are calculating in the first attempt. First off, you seem to be calculating the total number of pieces *possible* for the machine to serve in one week. In this statement:

> the machine can serve 2400/20 type 1 pieces per week = 120 and
>    2400 / 8 type 2 pieces per week = 300

you have calculated that, if the machine *only* processes type 1 pieces, it will be able to serve 120 type 1 peices in one week, and if the machine *only* processes type 2 pieces it will be able to serve 300 type 2 pieces in one week. It does not say that the machine can process type 1 pieces and type 2 pieces at the same time, so although it would be able to process (for instance) 300 type 2 pieces if that is all that it did, it would not be able to process any type 1 (perhaps).

The more pertinent problem with this line of thought is that you are told that you only receive 50 type 1 pieces and 100 type 2 pieces each week, so you cannot serve more pieces than you receive.

If you want to find the average service time per piece for the machine, that looks like

$$\text{Average Service Time Per Piece} = \frac{\text{time spent processing parts}} {\text{number of parts}}$$

Which is why, if you are given 50 parts per week which take 20 minutes each to process, and 100 parts per week which take 8 minutes each to process, you have

$$\text{time spent processing parts}=50*20+100*8=1800$$

and
$$\text{number of parts}=150$$

So
$$\text{Average Service Time Per Piece}=\frac{1800}{150}=12\ \text{min/piece}$$

Just think about the units you would want for "average service time per piece" - it should be some measurement of time divided by the number of pieces. Units help a lot in applied problems like this - if you checked the units in your first approach you would see that you are dividing a number of pieces by a number of pieces, which does not yield the units that you want.

Comment: Thank you, you are right I was dividing pieces by pieces and it's not what I wanted. Anyway I'm probably very stupid but it still isn't very easy to remember although now I know how to reason

Answer (score 2):

Your original wrong answer might be illustrated by

- the question of the average speed of a person who travels at 20 seconds per kilometre for 50 seconds and then at 8 seconds per kilometre for another 100 seconds,

compared with

- the question of the average speed person who travels at 20 seconds per kilometre for 50 kilometres and then at 8 seconds per kilometre for another 100 kilometres.

Average speed is total distance divided by total time so:

- For the first person the average speed is $\dfrac{\frac{50}{20} + \frac{100}{8}}{50 + 100} = \frac{1}{10}$ kilometres per second.
- For the second person the average speed is $\dfrac{50 + 100}{50 \times 20 + 100 \times 8} = \frac{1}{12}$ kilometres per second.

Multiply both answers by $2400$ seconds per week if it helps.

In your original question you were asked for the second method (the weights given are items not times) but initially answered using the first.